# Yii2 Validation rule for comparing email via another table and check for uniqueness on insert & update

Tags: yii2

We have 6 types of users on our website and they are managed on 3 different tables according to their property. & they are all linked with `user` table for a common login purpose. I am having an issue with a table where I have 2 emails like `personalEmail` and `businessEmail`. I want these emails & user table's email to be unique. Such that if 1 user has `test@test.com` email in the user table and his record in `application` table can have the same but for other users model should show error message.

```
[
    ['personalEmail', 'businessEmail'], 
    'unique', 
    'targetClass' => '\models\User', 
    'targetAttribute' => 'email', 
    'on'=>'insert,update', 
    'message' => '{attribute}:{value} already exists!'
],
```

I also want model to show error with respect to the column `businessEmail` from `application` model, currently its showing error as email from user table.

I want the model to keep the email unique & and also on an update, skip checking on the same record.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want unique email for both tables?

you must to use condition in rules

```
[['personalEmail'], 
   'unique', 
   'targetClass' => '\models\User', 
   'targetAttribute' => 'email', 
   'on'=>'insert,update', 
   'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) { 
       // Here you check by jQuery if businessEmail field is the same personalEmail 
   }"
   'message' => '{attribute}:{value} already exists!'
   ],
['personalEmail','customValidation'] // Custom Validation
```

in same model:

```
public function customValidation($attribute){
   // Here you can check your conditions
}
```

Then you repeat similar rules for businessEmail

Note: I did not test the code

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, I will give it a try.